# Is there any way that input method from Windows 10 Mobile can be used on Windows 10 Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages, windows-phone

On Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Mobile 10, Microsoft provided a Chinese input method known as Stroke Input Method for Traditional Chinese users.

I am used to and rely on this type of input method to input Chinese into computing devices.

However, this input method is not available on Windows PC edition, including Windows 10.

Is there anyway that could allow me to use the Windows 10 Mobile Input Method on Windows 10 PC?

I have tried similar input methods released by other vendors for the PC platform, but they are relatively subpar and does not meet my need.

Comment: win Fall Creators update 1709 MSFT added the mobile keyboard. maybe your input style is also included

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have asked others with the creator update installed to check it and there's no such input method there

Comment: it must be FALL creators update 1709 not 1703.

Comment: yes fall creator update 1709

Comment: send it as feedback in feedback hub and [tweet the link of the feedback to Donar Sakar](https://twitter.com/donasarkar)